# Remove all XML elements

Tags: xml, powershell

How to remove all XML nodes in a file?

Code:

```bsh
$xmlData = [xml](Get-Content -Path $xmlpath)
$xmlData | ForEach-Object {
    $_.ParentNode.RemoveAll()
    $xmlData.Save('D:\Scripts\test.xml')
}
```

I tried above script but it failed. Is there any builtin method for deleting all nodes?

Comment: If you remove everything anyway why even bother doing it that way and not just write a default file?

Comment: Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. What do you need this for?

Comment: am tried to erase all xml tags from a file.
i got one solution like  Clear-Content